# i need to link the js file in admin inside pdate layout xml tab in magento 2

Tags: magento2, admin, javascript, xml

I need to link a JS file in admin inside update layout xml tab in magento 2
please give if you any solution.

```
<head>
    <script src="js/productcollection.js">
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

To add JS via the update layout XML tab you only need the following code:

```
<head>
    <script src="Namespace_YourModule::js/productcollection.js"/>
</head>
```

Comment: i need to add the js link in admin cms page

Comment: Inside the update layout XML tab? If so just paste the code, if that doesn't work try it without the namespace and module.

Comment: i tried but i am not getting

Comment: There must be something else wrong then, I suspect either you need to clear cache, you have the namespace and module name wrong, or you have the file directory wrong. I've just tried the above code (replacing the example namespace with `Magento_Theme::` and it worked for me.